# Problema plunk laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

He tratado de contear un array por plunk(), por medio de un foreach, pero por alguna razon siempre queda en el primer elemento y no me cuenta el resto, a caso debo usar each()?

```html
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function reportes(Request $request)
    { 
        $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);

        $reporuser=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();

          foreach($reporuser as $reporuse)

          {

            $conteo=usuarios::where('usuario_ad',$reporuse);
            return  view('usuario.reportes',compact('conteo'));

          }

        
    }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Quiero que cuente todos los usuarios que halla ingresado un usuario

Mejor dicho, solo quiero hacer un foreach para que me cuente cada cosa dentro de esto,

```html
 $reporuser=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
```

pero con el foreach que hago solo sale un elemento y los otros no.

Comment: ¿qué deseas hacer? no queda clara la pregunta

Comment: lo unico que logro es que me cuente danielad y sus usuarios, pero no los de angelicaad

Comment: pon un json de ejemplo de que es lo que quieres como salida.

Comment: Técnicamente es imposible que el foreach se ejecute más de una vez, habiendo un return dentro de este.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creería que la solución más sencilla es agrupar y hacer un conteo, este es un caso típico:

```
usuarios::select('usuario_ad as usuario', DB::raw('count(*) as conteo'))
          ->groupBy('usuario_ad')
          ->get()
          ->pluck('conteo', 'usuario');
```

De ahí en adelante es jugar con el arreglo que entrega pluck

Comment: el método `pluck` no me queda muy claro su aplicación y uso serías tan amable de orientarme al respecto por favor?

Comment: @shadow dicho método genera un array con los valores seleccionados (uno es el valor y el otro que es opcional, la llave) de la colección. Una aplicación típica es «llenar» un `<select>`, en donde normalmente se pone un elemento como id en el atributo value, y un texto descriptivo entre los tags.

Comment: hecho me ha quedado claro, +1

Comment: Tengo varios usuarios en un campo usuario_ad como danielad pepito, danielad  julito,  danielad  andres, no puedo sacar en la consulta varios danielad, por eso uso el plunk y el unique() en esa columna

Comment: @zereft ¿ya probó la solución planteada? No entiendo para qué complicarse con pluck (con C), unique y un foreach con varios return (lo cual es más que incorrecto).

Comment: Eso tiene una razon de ser, sencillamente tengo un modulo que asi debe funcionar, y la solucion planteada debe funcionar, pero no estoy seguro con la sintaxis, no es como codigo nativo.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo la relación entre lo que haga un método y la salida que espere otro componente del sistema. Si alguien lo entiende, que me lo explique.

Comment: Solo quiero saber si se puede hacer un foreach a lo que actualice arriba, no se compliquen por relaciones que de eso ya me encargo yo, es otro asunto.