# Consulta sql a eloquen laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

de nuevo con mis preguntas novatas, alguien sabe como puedo traducir esta consulta a eloquent?

```
SELECT COUNT(nombre), usuario_ad 
FROM usuarios 
GROUP BY usuario_ad 
ORDER BY COUNT(nombre) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucion!

```
DB::table('usuarios')
              ->select('usuario_ad', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
              ->groupBy('usuario_ad')
              ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
              ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Ya había sido incluido en una respuesta a sus preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/222145/problema-plunk-laravel-5-5

Comment: Tienes razon, gracias.